# Comparing two large lists with multiple columns (same number in each list) in excel VBA and do...more stuff

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, compare

I've searched far and wide and I can't quite find anything to fit my needs.

The situation:
I have two lists of data with the same type data in each column (10 columns but the last 2 are useless), but the lists are of varying length (currently 55k in one, 18k in the other). The longer list is going to be a running list of items with the most up to date data in each column for the unique ID # in column A. The other list is linked to a SharePoint list that I update a couple times each day.

The need:
I need the list that updates from SharePoint to be compared to the running list. If there are matching Unique ID #'s in the lists, then the running list needs to be updated to the pulled data. If the running list doesn't contain a Unique ID that is in the pulled list, the new line needs to be added to the running list (which will be sorted later).

I first tried doing this with cell references in two for loops and for only 10 rows this worked fine. When I tried running it for every line, I had problems. So I tried using arrays instead, but this is new territory for me. The code seems to be working, but it's taking a really long time to run (I've let it go for 10 minutes before force stopping). I've tried adding some efficiency increases like turning off screen updating and calculations, but they shouldn't have any effect since I'm using arrays and not actually updating the cells until the array comparison is finished. If arrays are more efficient, great, but I don't know how to combine the data from the pulled list's array to the running list's array.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
Sub Data_Compile_Cells()

Dim sdata As Worksheet, spull As Worksheet
Dim p As Long, d As Long, c As Long
Dim lrdata As Long, lrpull As Long
Dim rdata As Range, rpull As Range
Dim Newvalue As Boolean
Dim apull As Variant, adata As Variant
Dim nrows As Long, ncols As Integer

Set sdata = Sheets("Data")
Set spull = Sheets("Data Pull")
Newvalue = "FALSE"
i = 1
apull = spull.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
adata = sdata.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

'lrdata = sdata.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'lrpull = spull.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

sdata.Activate

'*****UniqueID Check******

'Run through list of Unique ID's pulled from SharePoint
For p = 2 To UBound(apull, 1)
    'I tried to add a status bar to see if the code was actually running
    'Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & p & " of " & UBound(apull, 1) & " : " & Format(p / UBound(apull, 1), "0%")

    'Compare each one to the Unique ID's already listed
    For d = 2 To UBound(adata, 1)

        'Check for matching Unique ID's
        If adata(d, 1) = apull(p, 1) Then

            'Check each cell in the row with the matching Unique ID
            For c = 2 To 10
                'If a cell does not have the same data, replace the Data array value with the value from the Pull array
                If adata(p, c) <> apull(d, c) Then
                    adata(d, c) = apull(p, c)
                End If
            Next c
            'If a match is found, skip to the next p value
            Exit For

        Else
            Newvalue = "TRUE"
            'Need code to append new line to Data array
        End If

    Next d

Next p

'Sort the data
'Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=Range("A2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Any direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could an Id repeat more than once in each list? If not then your code could likely be much faster if you create a dictionary object for the Id column in the running list, mapping Id to row number. Then you can check `d.Exists(idValue)` which is *much* faster than looping over the array.

Comment: No, each ID will occur only once in each list. I'll look up some info on creating a dictionary object.

Comment: It looks like I don't have access to the scripting package, and probably won't be able to get access. I looked into using a collection instead and I don't think that's going to work because I'm going to need easy access to the key as well as the other information.

Comment: So you get an error if you try to run this. `Dim d: Set d = Createobject("scripting.Dictionary")` ?  Are you on a Mac?

Comment: Roughly what will be the % of checked records which are either 1) updates or 2) new line items ?

Comment: I can't really say what the % change will be on the first run. Subsequent runs could be changing up to 10k items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ran in <1 sec for me, using 20k rows "data", ~3k rows "pull" (mix of updates and new).

**EDIT**: tidied up and added some comments...

```
Sub tester()

    Const NUM_NEW As Long = 20000 'large enough ?
    Dim arrPull, arrData, arrDataId, arrNew()
    Dim ubP As Long, ubD As Long
    Dim numNew As Long, r As Long
    Dim v, c As Long
    Dim t, tmp, coll As Collection

    t = Timer
    'grab the current and new data
    arrPull = Sheets("Pull").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    arrData = Sheets("Data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value

    ubP = UBound(arrPull, 1)
    ubD = UBound(arrData, 1)
    numNew = 0

    ReDim arrNew(1 To NUM_NEW, 1 To 10) 'array for new data

    'create a collection to map ID to "row number"
    Set coll = New Collection
    For r = 1 To ubD
        coll.Add Item:=r, Key:=arrData(r, 1)
    Next r

    For r = 1 To ubP
        tmp = arrPull(r, 1)
        v = 0
        'collection has no "exists" function, so trap any error
        On Error Resume Next
        v = coll.Item(tmp)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If v > 0 Then
            'Id already exists: update data
            For c = 2 To 10
                arrData(v, c) = arrPull(r, c)
            Next c
        Else
            'new Id: add to the "new" array
            numNew = numNew + 1
            If numNew > NUM_NEW Then
                MsgBox "Need larger `new` array!"
                'a more sophisticated approach would be to dump the full
                '  array to the sheet and then redimension it for more
                '  data...
                Exit Sub
            End If
            For c = 1 To 10
                arrNew(numNew, c) = arrPull(r, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next r

    'drop updated and new (if any) to the worksheet 
    With Sheets("Data")
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value = arrData
        If numNew > 0 Then
            .Cells(ubD + 1, 1).Resize(numNew, 10).Value = arrNew
        End If
    End With

    Debug.Print "Done in " & Timer - t & " sec"

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like it could/should work. The first time I tried to run it (with mods to the actual sheet names) I got a type mismatch because not all of the data are string types. I added cstr(arrData(r,1) to the coll.add command. This seemed to fix the problem, but now the only thing it's capturing is cell A1. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes - you might need to coerce the Id's to string using `Cstr()` before adding them to the collection or comparing from the "pull" data.  My Id's happened to be strings already.

Comment: What do your id's look like - are they just numbers?  If it's not working then it's hard to say what the issue might be without seeing the workbook.

Comment: The whole column of unique ID's are numbers and formatted as such. I added the cstr to "tmp = " as well. Still only capturing the first cell. It looks like it's ending the script after it finds the first match (the first row is a header row).

Comment: I figured out the issue. It had to do with the way the data was put back into the cells. When you use Range("A1").CurrentRegion = arrData, excel only recognizes the current region as cell A1. I changed that line to ".Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(ubD, 10)) = arrData" and now it works perfectly! Thanks for the amazing fix. I'm going to remember to use collections in the future!

Answer (score 0):

You would  be better off using MSAccess to do this.  Link to both tables and then do an inner join on the id field or which ever field links the items in the two lists.